# How does the "Curve object Output" node from animation nodes work with loops?

Tags: animation-nodes

**I'm trying to Generate a bunch of random floating around objects which are connected by Splines.**

This is my node setup:
[image]

And this my result:
[image]

All of the splines are getting generated at the same position.

Why is this happening?
Doesn't the Curve Object Output work with Loops? And is there a way around it?

Comment: Can you try to activate "Deep Copy" in the Object Instancer that instances the curve?

Comment: @JacquesLucke thanks! that worked! Why is that?